# Android FragmentActivity finish close twice

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity and add fragment as below,

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, mFragment, mTag);
    ft.commit();
```

but when call activity finish(), The activity close as normal, so far so good, but after that the fragment show again and close. it's so fast that it's hard to see on some device (Nexus 4). but in Galaxy S3, it's obvious to see it flash and disappear. does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Are You doing anything with fragments UI in onPause(), onDestroy() or at corresponding fragments callbacks?

Comment: @ sandrstar I tried to use a plain fragment, it's still the same. I didn't have ft.addToBackStack(null); maybe that is the problem.

Comment: You should add the fragment to the backStack and in the onDestroy of you activity clear the backstack with the good flag

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment should be attached to the FragmentActivity that holds it, but you could try calling

```
fm.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
```

in the onStop() method of your FragmentActivity that way you can force the fragment to die before the Activity is completely gone.